# jQuery Animate divs up and down a stack

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have the following code to animate a dynamic div up and down. The idea is that there  could be any number of divs that need to be moved up and down the stack, swapping positions with the divs above and below. Once in their new position, I need to be able to catch that new re-odered position. The following code works, once, but once a lower div moves up and a upper moves down (swap spots) to the new positions, they stop working. How can I set this up so that they will continue to traverse up the stack, swapping the one immediately above or below as they go? I also need to know the new positions once finished to update the database. Ive been looking everywhere but can't seem to find how to do this. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
$('.editUp', this).click(function() {
   thisRowHt = $(this).parents('.rowCont').outerHeight();
   upperRowHt = $(this).parents('.rowCont').prev().outerHeight();
   $(this).parents('.rowCont').animate({'top': '-=' + thisRowHt + 'px'});
   $(this).parents('.rowCont').prev().animate({'top': '+=' + upperRowHt + 'px'});
   return false;
});

$('.editDown', this).click(function() {
   thisRowHt = $(this).parents('.rowCont').outerHeight();
   lowerRowHt = $(this).parents('.rowCont').next().outerHeight();
   $(this).parents('.rowCont').animate({'top': '+=' + lowerRowHt + 'px'});
   $(this).parents('.rowCont').next().animate({'top': '-=' + thisRowHt + 'px'});
   return false;
});
```

Comment: put a demo together in jsfiddle.net so others can visualize the problem you are having

Comment: have you tried this? http://jqueryui.com/sortable/ really easy to use :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should swap the elements in the DOM also, because when you animate the HTML elements, they just change theirs place on the screen.

I have completed your script:

```
$('.editUp', this).click(function() {

    var this_rowCont = $(this).parents('.rowCont');
    var prev_rowCont = $(this).parents('.rowCont').prev();

    // if this is the first element, it returns
    if (prev_rowCont.length != 1){return false;}

    thisRowHt = this_rowCont.outerHeight();
    upperRowHt = prev_rowCont.outerHeight();

    this_rowCont.animate({'top': '-=' + thisRowHt + 'px'});
    prev_rowCont.animate({'top': '+=' + upperRowHt + 'px'}, function(){

        // this is a callback function which is called, when the animation ends
        // This swap this and previous element in the DOM
        this_rowCont.insertBefore(prev_rowCont);
        this_rowCont.css("top", 0);
        prev_rowCont.css("top", 0);
    });

    return false;
});

$('.editDown', this).click(function() {

    var this_rowCont = $(this).parents('.rowCont');
    var next_rowCont = $(this).parents('.rowCont').next();

    // if this is the last element, it returns
    if (next_rowCont.length != 1){return false;}

    thisRowHt = this_rowCont.outerHeight();
    lowerRowHt = next_rowCont.outerHeight();

    this_rowCont.animate({'top': '+=' + lowerRowHt + 'px'});
    next_rowCont.animate({'top': '-=' + thisRowHt + 'px'}, function(){

        // This swap this and next element in the DOM
        next_rowCont.insertBefore(this_rowCont);
        this_rowCont.css("top", 0);
        next_rowCont.css("top", 0);
    });

   return false;
});​
```

You can see it in action here: [Animate div up and down](http://jsfiddle.net/ykzwT/2/)

Comment: Dave - I really appreciate this detailed answer. I will implement this tomorrow morning and see if i can dial it in. Thanks :)

Comment: You are welcome. :) If my answer helped you, please give me a vote up for this answer. If it didn't helped and you have more questions please ask.

Comment: Hey David - works wonderfully, however, for some reason the top most `var prev_rowCont = $(this).parents('.rowCont').prev();` is catching the heading div above that does not have the class 'rowCont'. So its including it in the stack as the top most div. Any ideas?

Comment: I got it, just had to move the `.rowCont` into the `.prev()` `var prev_rowCont = $(this).parents().prev('.rowCont');` Thanks again for your help.